# Can two buttons be touching in XCode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am new to the iOS development world so please be gentle if this a "Stupid" question. The project I am working on has two buttons that allows to swap between viewing of 2 different tables. Our users have stated that they would like a segmented controller if possible. This is just a "Nice to Have" option they wanted.

What we decided to do is fake the segmented controller by pushing the buttons against each other to give the same look to the user. But the problem is, even though the buttons are together, not overlapping, in the storyboard there is still whitespace between them when the simulator runs.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task or is it impossible to eliminate the whitespace between buttons?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your buttons look like? Is there a background image or something that is actually inset from the edge?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have no white space between buttons, although it seems as though you are going through a lot of trouble to replicate the "nice to have" functionality of the segmentControl when it is much simpler to implement a segmented control to do the things you are trying to do.

Getting past that, in the storyboard, add a horizontal spacing constraint between the two buttons and make sure the constant for the constraint is set to 0.

Comment: I have tried this, going from left button to right button, and set the constraint to 0. The white space still remains. We have a custom class for the two buttons and since it is a "nice to have" feature we kind of took the "easy" path to see if we can fake it, or get it as close as possible if not.

Comment: Double check your size classes. I've been in situations where changes weren't being reflected in the simulator and the issue happened to be that I had set constraints in iPhone portrait mode e.g. Compact Width, Regular Height then working on the same controller but in Any Width, Any Height mode.

Comment: There is a chance that your custom class is the issue.  The button frames might in fact be touching but the button layout in the custom class might be creating that extra space that you are seeing.  There are several ways to debug this but the quickest is to toggle color blended layers on the simulator.  Debug > Color Blended Layers, that should give you a good idea of the frame of each view.